# Getting an error while sorting the date in a table from Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

> An error occurred while calling o84.collectToPython.
> org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary

```
raw_customers = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "postgresql_processed", table_name = "prodplfm_plf_customers").toDF()
latest_partition=raw_customers.select("process_date").orderBy(desc("process_date")).limit(1).collect()[0][0]
customers=raw_customers.filter("process_date='"+latest_partition+"'")
customers.createOrReplaceTempView("customers")
```

Comment: please share the data that you are trying to sort.

Comment: The main table is in the s3 folder like s3://profectus-rawdata/PostgreSQL/prodplfm_plf_customers/     Inside this we have multiple folder containing dates like..  process_date=2019-09-01/  |  process_date=2019-03-02/  |  process_date=2019-03-03/  . Inside each these folders we have one parquet file. But that parquet file doestnt contain the process_date column.

Comment: The above code is written by someone else...

Comment: @Lucasz Was I able to express my point?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to help you futher. please try to put all related information in your post.

Comment: that is all I have... Anything specific you need @Lucasz?

Comment: The parquet file does not need to contain the process_date column, because it is already contained in your folder structure as your partition_key. The problem is likely a schema mismatch. In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Thanks @RobertKossendey , there was schema mismatch in one of my partition thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There was schema mismatch in one of my partition. I removed that partition-> deleted the glue database -> Ran the crawler again and it worked.